# vagrant sequel pro SSH Tunnel remote host can't connect, bad password

Tags: mysql, vagrant, sequelpro

I'm new to MySQL and Vagrant and spent several hours trying to set both up. I can connect to MySQL from the command line with:

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --password=[my_password]
```

I'm trying to connect with Sequel Pro and following a couple tutorials have set up Vagrant/MySQL correctly, I believe. I'm trying to connect thru SSH and tried many combinations of username/password. I believe the correct inputs are:

MySQL Host: 127.0.0.1

username: root

password: [my_password]

SSH Host: 127.0.0.1

SSH User: vagrant

SSH Key: insecure_private_key

SSH Port: 2222

however I'm still getting the error "The SSH Tunnel could not authenticate with the remote host. Please check your password and ensure you still have access."

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following configuration and leave everything else blank. (Of course specify MySQL root password if you've set it up.)

`MySQL Host: 127.0.0.1
Username: root
Port: 3306
SSH Host: 127.0.0.1
SSH User: vagrant
SSH Key: ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
SSH Port: 2222`

Comment: I still get the error "permission denied(publickey.password)"

Comment: How are you specifying ssh key?

Comment: @KM617 Try chmod 400 ~/path/to/pem

Answer (score 4):

You need to choose `SSH` connection type and select the correct private key.

[image: Sequel Pro SSH connection with private key]

For Vagrant 1.6 and older, the private key is located in `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`. For Vagrant 1.7 and above, the private key is located in  `.vagrant/machines/[vm_name]/virtualbox/private_key` where the `Vagrantfile` is located.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and this solved the issue for me.

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

For me work added my key identity

`ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa`